# Spring Boot: Знаки вопроса вместо имени файла

Tags: java, linux, spring, thymeleaf

Знаки вопроса вместо русского названия файла, однако только на проде под пингвинусом. Английские же имена файлов читает как надо.

HTML форма:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"> // В head

<form th:method="POST" th:action="@{'/profile/edit-' + ${user.id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:object="${user}">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="input-file" accept="image/*" name="avatar"/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger" value="Сохранить">
</form>
```

Контроллер:

```
@PostMapping("/profile/edit-{id}")
public String editUser(
        @PathVariable int id,
        @ModelAttribute User userModel,
        @RequestParam(required = false) MultipartFile avatar
        ) {

    log.info(avatar.getOriginalFileName());

    return "main";
}
```

Файл отправляю с формы прямиком на бэк. При добавлении в инпут название файла читается нормально, проверил с помощью js.

При отправке файла май.png

Вывод: ???.png

Comment: Недостаточная мощность кодировки.

Comment: @Roman C чегоо, а что же делать? Я вот думаю, может это в линуксе проблема, т.к русские символы в консоли да и в файлах не воспринимает как надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была с кодировкой в системе Linux. Настроил так:

1. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`
2. `rm /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive`
3. `locale-gen`
4. `dpkg-reconfigure locales` -> выбрал всё, чтобы наверняка
5. Перезапустил сервер

Пользовался этим ресурсом: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/desktop/9986976

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Спасибо за совет, дополнил!